# Weird glitches in After Effects render

Tags: after-effects, animation-rendering

was wondering if any of you knew how to fix this issue. When I render my comp in After Effects, I see these weird glitches in the render (like black triangular spots of missing video).

I have uploaded an example of the issue here:

Comment: I had something similar recently and - sorry to say - didn't find a solution. I assume in my case it was / is a bug in the effect used. It had to do with masks / alpha channel but since I needed to use a specific mask, I couldn't work around the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Put a black solid in the background. It worked for me.